# Description of $S_4/H$ as a set where $H$ is order $8$ subgroup of $S_4$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, quotient-group

Let $H$ be subgroup of $S_4$ of order $8$. It is conjugate of $\langle (1,2,3,4),(2,4)\rangle $. I would like to specify $S_4/H$ as a set. $S_4/H$ is order $3$, so the set is like $\{ id,\sigma H,\tau H\}$. I would like to specify $\sigma $ and $\tau$.

I would like to know the process of finding $\sigma, \tau$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: $S_4$ is the group of direct symmetries (rotations) of a cube (the cube has 4 diagonals and they get permuted by rotations of the cube). The set $S_4/H$ is then the set of the 3 axes of the cube (the 3 lines connecting the centers of the opposite faces of the cube).

Comment: There was an identical question asked and answered last week.

Comment: Could you tell me the question ? I couldn't find that. I asked this 2 days ago.

Comment: Three cosets, each with 8 elements. So $8^3$ possible correct answers without having a reason to prefer one over the other. Even if you fix the neutral element to represent the coset $H$, there are still 64 ways???

Answer (score -1):

First, lets recall that in this setting, $id$ is just H.

Now take an element $\sigma \in S_4-H$.
Since this element is not in H, you get that $\sigma H\ne H$.

Take $\tau \in S_4 - (H \cup \sigma H)$ and you get $\tau H \ne \sigma H \land \tau H \ne H$.

So $S_4/H = \{H, \sigma H, \tau H\}$.